# How to tell when a D3 force layout has stopped

Tags: javascript, events, layout, d3.js, force-layout

I'm using D3's force layout to organize a network graph, and everything works smoothly.

However, I want to add a button to my UI so that the user can play/pause the layout process at will: I'd like to have a toggle button that reflects the current state of the layout: whether it's computing or not (d3 automatically will stop computing when the layout has stabilized). Is there a way to tell when force layout computing has finished and started? I expected some kind of event to handle this, but couldn't find one.

Answer (score 15):

Use the `end` event documented on the [wiki](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-on).

```
d3.layout.force()
   .on('end', function() { console.log('ended!'); });
```

jsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zschuessler/gRqv3/ | View console to see listeners in action.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a notion of having "stopped" computing the layout. Even when it looks like it's stationary, there may still be tiny changes. What you can do is check the value of [`alpha`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Force-Layout#wiki-alpha) and interpret it as stopped if it falls below a threshold. In this case, you can set it to a negative value which will stop the layout explicitly. There is no specific event for this, but you can check your condition in the `tick` event handler.

Comment: Hi, Lars. The 'end' event listener has been available since v2.8.0. (rel Feb 24 2012). jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zschuessler/gRqv3/

Comment: Good catch! It might still be safer to check alpha as well, since it my take a very long time for it to be actually zero.